# How to trim extracted string from file?

Tags: string

I am working on compressed file who contained many file in it

This compressed file is have header that contain contained file size and file name

But length of size and name is different in any file and the header structure for example say name is 20 byte of file

I extracted this value but for correct use i need to remove null char from it for do this i insert extracted value in textbox and then read it from textbox

But I think this is not correct way

Can anybody help me?

```
string filename = retval(0, 20); 
textBox1.Text = filename;
strtofile(textBox1.Text, filecontent);
```

Comment: It helps if you tag the question with the language you're using.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using C#, just call `.Trim()` on the string that you want to trim.

Answer (score 0):

when appending hexstring to StringBuilder if it not equal 00 apend